# Vue3 + Ionic + Sanctum mobile authenthication gives back 419

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, ionic-framework, laravel-sanctum

I am trying to perform a simple token authentication on my Vue3 Ionic mobile app. I have two separate repositories - one the API in Laravel 10 backend and the other one is the Vue3 Ionic app, and I am using Sanctum for my Laravel 10 API auth.

This is my API auth endpoint:

```php
public function createToken(CreateToken $request): JsonResponse
    {

        Log::info('LOGIN MOBILE REQUEST', [
            'request' => $request->all(),
            'token' =>  $request->user
                ->createToken($request->deviceName)
                ->plainTextToken
        ]);
        return response()->json([
            'token' => $request->user
                ->createToken($request->deviceName)
                ->plainTextToken
        ]);
    }
```

The problem is that when I am hitting my auth endpoint on mobile app very strangely I am getting 419 back which is CSRF thing which is for session based auth. I don't understand how and why I am getting 419 from mobile app. When I am testing on mobile phone I am simply launching it via Android studio on my phone. I am also using Expose for my API and the URL from Expose goes into mobile app config. All the API calls work just fine it's just I cannot make Laravel understand this has nothing to do with CSRF.

To make it a bit stranger - when I test the same login funcitonality on the desktop I get my token no problem even though apart from installing and initual setup I didn't do any extra configuration of anything.

Does anyone know what could it be?

Comment: Aside the issue in title, why don’t you store token into variable at beginning of the method, then use variable itself instead creating token anytime it’s needed in method?

Comment: Not quite sure if I follow. There's no need to store the token in any variable. This method is supposed to create a new token for me every time I hit it.

Comment: `$token = $request->user
                ->createToken($request->deviceName)
                ->plainTextToken;`, then use `$token` variable later in method.

Comment: This is completely redundant. All the method does is returning a new token, and there's no further usage so extracting it to another variable servers no purpose at all (of course please note that Log::info is there just for debugging purposes and will be gone in final version).

Comment: I haven't checked myself but I would say that anytime `createToken` is used, one gets different string because `Str::random()` method is [used](https://github.com/laravel/sanctum/blob/10e6ef24c67336aec50c5498c6673990b1305f97/src/HasApiTokens.php#L48) inside.

Comment: What does it have to do with extra variable you proposed? How token is generated, stored and where it comes from is completely irrelevant. Besides it's not important now as you can see below problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I know what it was. In case someone else has the same issue. Out of habbit I followed the documentation and enabled `\Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,` in the `app/Http/Kernel.php` as my app will also need web auth as well.

So that will have to be dealt with some conditional middleware where I will apply it based on the platform I guess.